# How to show popup with the current record on click of Edit image on the record in vf

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

[image]Here is my vf---

---

```
Controller-
public class AccountControllerWithPopup {
    public list<wrapperclass> wrapperlist{get;set;}
    public AccountControllerWithPopup(ApexPages.StandardController controller){ 

    }
    public list<wrapperclass> getWrapperObj(){
        list<Account> acclist=[select  id,name,site,industry from account limit 15];
        wrapperlist=new list<wrapperclass>();
        for(Account acc:acclist){
            wrapperlist.add(new wrapperclass(acc,false));
        }
        return wrapperlist; 
    }
    public class wrapperclass{
        public account accobj{get;set;}
        public boolean checkbox{get;set;}
        public wrapperclass(Account accRec,Boolean selectbox){
            accobj=accRec;
            checkbox=selectbox;
        }  
    }
}
```

I need to display on click of Edit image -popup needs to be open for editing that record

Comment: you haven't set the "url" in the javascript function in window.open();

Comment: Not required.  You can use "/e" to get to the edit record.  Example:  https://na02.salesforce.com/xxxxxxx/e?retURL=%2Fxxxxxxx

Comment: your's is not a standard page right? and your page has outputFields? So 1) you need to create another VF page for the edit screen (and the fields will be apex:inputField) OR
2) In the same VF Page, you need to have both outputField and inputField.  on button click (image), you need render inputFields and hide outPutFields.   Outputfields will be for View layout,  InputField will be for EDIT layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the url value in the popup window javascript function

```
    <script>         
         var newWin=null;
         function openPopup(id)
         {
          var url="/apex/LookupVFPage?id=" + id;
          newWin=window.open(url, 'Popup','height=500,width=600,left=100,top=100,resizable=no,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,status=no');    
         }
    </script>
```